# C#, rotating 2D arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I've looked at other post on rotating 2D arrays, but it's not quite what I want.
I want something like this

```
 int[,] original= new int[4,2]
       {
           {1,2},
           {5,6},
           {9,10},
           {13,14}
       };
```

I want to turn it like this, 
    rotatedArray = { {1,5,9,13}, {2,6,10,14}};
I want to do some analysis by column, as opposed to by rows.

This works, but is there an easier way??

```
 private static int[,] RotateArray(int[,] myArray)
  {
        int org_rows = myArray.GetLength(0);
        int org_cols = myArray.GetLength(1);

        int[,] myRotate = new int[org_cols, org_rows];

        for (int i = 0; i < org_rows; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < org_cols; j++)
            {
                myRotate[j, i] = myArray[i, j];
            }
        }

        return myRotate;
    }
```

Is there an easy way to iterate through columns in c#?
B

Comment: It would be much simpler if you would use another way of arrays:
int[][] instead of int[,]

Answer (score 8):

If you change your array to be an array of arrays it gets easier. I found this if you change it to an int[][]:

```
int[][] original = new[]
                                   {
                                       new int[] {1, 2},
                                       new int[] {5, 6},
                                       new int[] {9, 10},
                                       new int[] {13, 14}
                                   };
```

and the rotate method:

```
private static int[][] Rotate(int[][] input)
{
    int length = input[0].Length;
    int[][] retVal = new int[length][];
    for(int x = 0; x < length; x++)
    {
        retVal[x] = input.Select(p => p[x]).ToArray();
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tigraine, I will have to modify my calling function a bit, but that's okay

Comment: I'm not perfectly happy with it. But with  [,] the enumerator goes through all elements of both dimensions, and that makes it a bit harder..

Comment: This also works with the [][] array, I just had to modify my calling a bit to use [][], but the [,] is much easier to use though. 
I just did a bit of googling on this and apparently, (to my surprise) [][] is quicker than [,]

Comment: Probably because there is less pointer arithmetic involved to determine a memory address. Since [1,2] = 1*length*datatype_len+2*datatype_len while int[] only involves index*datatype_len..