# Inserting column in jagged array

Tags: c#, linq, jagged-arrays

```
int RowCount; //This will be approx in the range 1,00,000
int[][] SourceJaggedArray;
int ColumnCount; //This is will be approx in the range 15 - 20
```

Currently I am populating value for all columns for each row which is very slow. But according to business logic, I know for atleast 5 columns all the values are -1 and for about 5 columns all the values are same (but comes from a variable).

Therefore I want to know is there an efficient way to populate jagged array by inserting an array to the particular column index:

```
SourceJaggedArray[][0] = firstColumnArray;
SourceJaggedArray[][1] = secondColumnArray;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess not very efficient and not exactly what you want but...

1 option could be to do something like

```
int[][] SourceJaggedArray=new int[20][];
SourceJaggedArray[0]=firstColumnArray;
SourceJaggedArray[1]=secondColumnArray;
```

Then rotate your array jagged array if necessary(refer to [C#, rotating 2D arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729192/c-rotating-2d-arrays))

2nd option which I like better, would be

```
List<int[]> source=new List<int[]>();
source.Add(firstColumnArray);
source.Add(secondColumnArray);
```